# Take 1 hour from time field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an time field which is in string format 'varchar' and I wish to convert this field to a time and take an hour from the converted value so that if I have 14:22 in the field I would get 13:22 in the converted value.  How would I do this in a view?

Comment: What database system are you using? Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, etc? The date/time manipulation functions available in each aren't necessarily the same as what the [tag:sql] standard specifies.

Comment: Sorry I am using SQL server 2008!  I am trying to build the function into an existing query which takes the existing fields and concatenates them to form an VARCHAR(10) field.  The existing query field looks like:  CASE WHEN NOT szcollectiontime = '' THEN CONVERT (VARCHAR(10) , Comp2.dbo.Jobitem.dtCollectionDate , 103) + ' ' + Comp2.dbo.Jobitem.szCollectionTime ELSE CONVERT (VARCHAR(10) , Comp2.dbo.Jobitem.dtCollectionDate , 103) + ' ' + '00:00' END . If I try to change the query to incorporate the function suggested I get errors.

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server, you can use the following query:

```
select dateadd(hh,-1 ,cast(timecolumn as time)) from tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

If using MySQL, use `DATE_SUB` to subtract a time period.

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(timefield, INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AS timefield_minus_hour
```

Answer (score 1):

This works with MS SQL 2012: [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/500ad/8)

> SELECT DATEADD(HH,-1 ,CAST(stringTime as time)) FROM myTable

Comment: thanks fabigler. Fiddle demo preparation took time I suppose. +1 for same approach.